# Numerical smooth interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods

I want to learn smooth interpolation but when I searched to find a website to read about this I could not find anything. Please suggest a source or put a link.

Comment: Interpolation is a very big area with thousands of methods. What kind of data and needs do you have?

Comment: @mathreadler Do you know type of interpolation method that called smooth interpolation? someone told me study interpolation and one of this content is smooth interpolation.

Comment: Almost any of the methods which are a bit more involved than nearest neighbour interpolation could be called "smooth" interpolation.

Comment: So this is not one way such as Lagrange.

Comment: How would I know what someone saying this would mean. "smooth interpolation" could mean almost any method.

Comment: @mathreadler Thank you

Comment: As mathreadler said, smooth interpolation could mean a number of techniques. Spline interpolation approaches can provide smooth interpolation (for instance B-Splines).